# Process address deposit from contract

Tags: parity, contract-invocation

Our service handles thousands (currently 10000+) of users and each user has his own Ethereum deposit address. To detect a new deposit we:

1. Scan each block to get a list of transactions
2. Get a list of destination addresses for all transactions in the block.
3. Filter addresses that belong to our users
4. Get transactions for these addresses and handle each transaction

But this does not work if there is a transaction for a contract with the internal transaction (transfer) to one of our deposit address.

So my question is: What is the best way to handle transfers via contracts to thousands of our addresses?

We use Parity wallet with trace mode enabled

Comment: Try [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts). Specifically in this page, check out the `Get a list of 'Internal' Transactions by Address` option.